# "... is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer" in a project targeting iOS 15.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, watchkit

I'm using Xcode 13.4 and have created a new SwiftUI project using the "iOS app with watch app" project template. The target for the main app is set to iOS 15.5 and the watch target is set to WatchOS 8. Everything was building and running on the simulator fine.

I've just added the [watch-date-picker Swift package](https://swiftpackageindex.com/freyaariel/watch-date-picker) (a package which adds a date picker for WatchOS) to my project using Xcode's `File -> Add packages...` menubar option:

[image]

and now I can't build my project - I get tons of errors in the added watch-date-picker package's code complaining that various things are `only available in iOS 13.0 or newer`. I haven't even tried using the library yet - I've just added it via `File -> Add Packages`. Here are the package settings:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.5
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "watch-date-picker",
  defaultLocalization: "en",
  platforms: [
    .watchOS(.v8)
  ],
  products: [
    .library(name: "WatchDatePicker", targets: ["WatchDatePicker"]),
  ],
  targets: [
    .target(name: "WatchDatePicker", dependencies: []),
    //.executable(name: "WatchDatePickerExamples", dependencies: ["WatchDatePicker"]),
  ]
)
```

I'm confused why I'm getting this error - as far as I can tell, I'm targeting the latest versions of everything - iOS 15.5 and WatchOS 8.5. Can anyone explain why this is and what I can do to resolve it? Am I missing something? Is there something I need to do to tell the package to only build for WatchOS and not iOS? I've tried cleaning, deleting derived data, closing Xcode, nothing works. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It’s not easy to guess what the problem is. Have you tried cocoapods?

Comment: Looks like a general problem with the package  see https://swiftpackageindex.com/freyaariel/watch-date-picker/builds Looks like you target something with the package out of the scope of it But it is not to see with the information you provide

Comment: Show your package file settings. You need to set the platforms  `platforms: [ .iOS(.v13) ],`

Comment: @LeoDabus I've added the package settings to the question - it's set to `platforms: [.watchOS(.v8)]`, which makes sense because it's a package specifically targeted at Watch (it adds a date picker for Watch). Is there some way to tell Xcode that this package is just for the WatchOS extension and not the main iOS target?

Comment: @popeinvestor thanks, maybe this is a problem with the package - I've raised an issue on the package's GitHub

Comment: "Is there some way to tell Xcode that this package is just for the WatchOS extension and not the main iOS target?" It sounds like you may have added the package incorrectly to your project. There are dependency settings that should determine how the various targets are related. "I've just added the watch-date-picker Swift package (a package which adds a date picker for WatchOS) to my project" Yes, but how and where exactly? You have choices to make when you do that. You haven't told us anything about that.

Answer (score 5):

Modify `Package.swift` from

```
// swift-tools-version:5.5
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "watch-date-picker",
  defaultLocalization: "en",
```

to

```
// swift-tools-version:5.5
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "watch-date-picker",
  platforms: [.iOS(.v15)],
  defaultLocalization: "en",
```

I do not understand why. But, this is the workaround I am using so far. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a package, you say what target it belongs to. It sounds like you neglected to make this package part part of the Watch target at the time you added it.

I would suggest removing the package entirely and starting over.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see any options to do that via `File -> Add packages` in Xcode - I've added a screenshot of what I see. There is only one option under 'Add to project', which is the whole project - no options for choosing a target. How do you make a package part of the Watch target?